# Is is possible to create App Parts from an MVC project?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, visual-studio, app, mvc, app-part

"https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/93f5ec98-5aeb-40b7-add0-0e83280a6555/is-is-possible-to-create-app-parts-from-an-mvc-project"

I am now interested to see if I can create an App Part based on the MVC site.

I have got as far as adding a Client Web Part (Host Web) and it gives me two options.

The first option - Create a new client web part page adds a WebPart page to the SharePoint App project but I am not sure what I need to do next.

The second option - Select or enter a URL for an existing web page doesnt give me any options in the drop down list.

I have seen instructions on how to create App Parts based Web Forms based applications but nothing on doing it with MVC based apps so I dont know if this is even possible

Has anyone else managed to do this?

Could somone please respond with instructions, that will be very helpful !!

Thanks,
Pandiarajan K

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:
MVC AppPart Controller template has been included in the recent Visual Studio 2013 (Update 4)

phew :)